# Can't print on OS X Lion via shared printer connected to Windows Vista. Fix?

Tags: macos, mac, windows, printing

As the title states I am not able to print from my Mac to a shared printer that is hooked up to my Windows PC running Windows Vista. I am currently running OS X Lion 10.7 on a Mac Mini. My Mac is able to find and add the printer on my network to its list of printers. However when it comes to printing a document the status of the print job becomes: **"On Hold (Authentication Required)"** regardless if I correctly enter the correct credentials of the PC which the printer is connected to.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? How do I fix it?

Notes: Printer is a Cannon MP210 and I have the most recent drivers for it.

Comment: To me this seems like the authentication/permissions settings on the Windows box are the problem. Which leads me to wonder wether this should be asked here at Ask Different.

Comment: What is showing in the /var/log/cups/error_log ? there might be an earlier or later error indicating the true cause of the problems.

Comment: @macaco I am still able to print from another laptop running Windows to this printer. My networked Mac computer isn't able to however. Also I have looked at the error_log and there is a section where it says that it has failed to print because of unauthorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this thread on macrumors, [Lion - Printing to shared Windows 7 Printer](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1203336.html), Apple has decided to remove in OS X Lion anything that allows you to print via a windows shared printer.

Answer (score 3):

IN my situation the error was caused by a changed password. In the keychain the old password was registered and used during printing.

I solved to problem as follow:

- Open the KeyChain Access App (Applications -> Utilities -> Key Chain Access)
- Search for your printer name
- Open the key chain entry found
- Change the password

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My Canon MX328 is connected and shared on Windows 7. I could print test-page but not others.

Try the following.
1. Select job and press hold on menu bar. Use "guest/guest" for Authentication. This solve problem for my Kyocera laser printer shared on Windows 7, but not Canon inkjet.
2. If still couldn't print (like me for Canon inkjet). Use Gutenprint driver instead of Maker's.

CHeers

Comment: Use `guest` as user name when it's asked (password it not required). If not (print job "wait for authentification"), open keychain app ("Trousseaux d'accès" in french) and delete the password entry for the shared printer and try again

https://discussions.apple.com/message/16442328#16442328

Answer (score 0):

This comment in the MacRumors thread fixed it for me:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13090087&postcount=2

Basically go to the CUPS web admin, modify the printer and add the username/password to the samba url for the printer, i.e:

```
smb://username:password@pcname/printername
```

I'm on Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

In my case just using the username "guest" was enough, I guess the Windows PC was setup to allow guest users to print.

(The generic postscript driver didn't work though. :( )